# Xml.TransformNode(xmldoc) is not supporting in Firefox,chrome,edge

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xslt

**This is the function iam calling to load the data in div**

```
function createApproverList(div, locationId, value)
{
    try
    {
    var url = "dbXML?conn=webddev&sql=Select logon_id, sec_last_name || ', ' || sec_first_name  technician_name from w_security where rec_del_flg = 0 AND type_id = 3 order by sec_last_name";

    var xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xml.async = false;
    xml.load(url);
    div.innerHTML = xml.transformNode(approverXSL.XSLDocument);
    document.frmEntry.approverId.value = value;
    }
    catch (e) {
          console.error(e.name + ': ' + e.message)
        }
    }
```

**But it is working fine internet explorer and not in other browsers so, please help me by converting above one to support in firefox,chrome,edge browsers**

**Thanks in advance!.**..

Comment: An introduction to the API Mozilla introduced for running XSLT 1 from JavaScript in its browsers and which has subsequently adopted by Chrome and Edge is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  could you please help me by providing entire conversion of above function